PowerShell for Visual Studio Code not starting, how to fix?
If you look at the picture below, there is an arrow that points to a cycle icon, that icon keeps spinning while I am asking for the PowerShell to start, but it does not.

The message that  PowerShell has not started:

the settings.json file:
{
    "powershell.developer.setExecutionPolicy": false,
    "powershell.enableProfileLoading": false,
    "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "windows Powershell (x64)",
    "powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable": false,
    "powershell.startAsLoginShell.osx": false
}

the launch.json file:

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "powershell.integratedConsole.suppressStartupBanner": true,
            "name": "PowerShell: Launch Current File",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${file}",
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}

the PowerShell extension for VSCode:

